# How long do crashed UFO's last?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

I shot down a UFO, but a few of my "must have" soldiers are recovering from wounds. I would like to send them in 4 days, or 2 if I had to. Will the crash site disappear or otherwise go bad if I wait too long? If so, how long is too long?

Comment: why not take this opportunity to train up some rookies? :)

Comment: @spartacus I've had this happen when I was waiting for the rookies to arrive (it was either wait or send out a 2 man squad :\ )

Answer (score 36, accepted):

These are the timers for all game modes in hours taken from game data:

UFO_CRASH_TIMER = 48
TERROR_TIMER = 30
UFO_LANDED_TIMER = 30
ABDUCTION_TIMER = 30

Comment: This is very useful info! Is there also a timer for how long you have to shoot down a flying UFO?

Comment: Just to add expansion info : These times are unchanged in Enemy Within.

Answer (score 5):

Based on some testing:

1. On Normal, I have observed several of scout-classed UFOs take between 24 and 48 hours before being "repaired" and disappearing.
2. On classic, I have observed two scout-classed UFOs taking between 24 an 30+ hours to disappear.

Small sample sizes, and I don't know if bigger ships are more or less likely to take off quickly.

Comment: I'm playing on NORMAL with ironman and a medium crash site just vanished in about 17 hours. Dammit! So the advice of 24-48 is not accurate.